# Не получается написать декоратор для удаления файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file
from PIL import Image
import requests
import shutil
import os
import glob


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

def delete_user_image(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        for image in glob.glob("image.*"):
            os.remove(image)
    return wrapper

@delete_user_image
@app.route("/convert", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def convert():
    response = requests.get(request.form.get("url"), stream=True)
    print(request.form.get("url"))
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open("image.png", "wb") as file:
            response.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, file)
    image = Image.open("image.png")
    rgb_image = image.convert("RGB")
    rgb_image.save("image." + request.form["filetype"])
    return send_file("image." + request.form["filetype"], as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

У меня есть функция для того чтобы пользователь мог получить некий файл, это файл скачивается по ссылке, предоставленной пользователем, когда я возвращаю ему файл, он по задумке он должен удалиться.
Можете, пожалуйста, предложить решение моей проблемы, мне нужно чтобы в конце convert файлы удалялись, если есть более красивые решения, чем декораторы, тоже давайте.
Спасибо)

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал посмотреть в сторону tempfile - https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Comment: А что не работает или работает не так в этом решении? Вообще-то у вас тут проблема явная с тем, что декоратор не возвращает результат из декорируемой функции - wrapper должен в конце вернуть т.е. сделать `return val`, где val это значение из фукции `val = func(*args, **kwargs)`